# Regular expression to extract version number

Tags: regex, sed

I want to extract the version number from the `ld -v` command and I have written the following `sed` expression:

```
ld -v | sed -r 's/.+([0-9|\.]+)/\1/'
```

However this outputs `1`, which is the last digit of the version number. The result I expect is `2.35.1`

Where did I go wrong with my regular expression? How I understand it the `.+` part matches all characters and whitespace and `([0-9|\.]+)` matches a digit or a dot and then captures this. `\1` then references the captured bit.

Comment: Try `ld -v | awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: "Where did I go wrong with my regular expression?" The `+` in `.+` is greedy and matches all characters not matched by the remaining regex. Result: 1 char matched by `[0-9|\.]+`, hence the output of `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Use GNU `grep` like so:

```
ld -v | grep -Po '[\d.]+' | head -n1
```

Output:

```
2.25.1
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`[\d.]+` : Any digit or a literal dot, repeated 1 or more times.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` instead, with the `-o` option to extract just the matched component:

```
ld -v | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$'
```

Note this also anchors the match to the *end* of the line.

The pattern itself allows for any amount of `.` in it. Generally, version numbers have a `MAJOR`, `MINOR` and `PATCH` -- so at most 2 `.`, but it doesn't hurt to match more in this case.

You could be more specific, and only match up to two `.`:

```
ld -v | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,2}$'
```

Note: in both cases, we allow for situations where the version number may omit the `MINOR` and/or `PATCH` -- e.g. version 2.35 rather than 2.35.1

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
ld -v | 
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+$/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
ld -v |                                ##Running ld -v command and sending output to awk program from here.
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+$/){     ##using match function to match digits followed by dot with 1 ore more occurrences and then digits till last of line.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)      ##Printing sub string of matched regex which prints from RSTART to till RLENGTH values.
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
ld -v | sed -rn 's/.+ ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
```

**Details**

- `-r` (or `-E`) - enables POSIX ERE expression syntax
- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `.+ ([0-9.]+).*` - matches any one or more chars, a space, and then captures one or more digits and `.` into Group 1, and then any zero or more chars
- `\1` - replaces the match with Group 1 contents
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.